# TFileStream кодировка иероглифами, как исправить?

Tags: delphi, pascal, pdf

При загрузке pdf файла в TFileStream кодировка иероглифами, как исправить?
код:

```
sStream := TFileStream.Create(aPDF, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
GetMem(pBuf, sStream.size); 
cnt := sStream.Read(pBuf^, sstream.size);
```

в результате:

```
pBuf '倥䙄ㄭ㈮ഠㄊ〠漠橢'#$0A0D'㰼'#$0A0D'启灹'#$2065'䌯瑡污杯'#$0A0D'.... и т.д.
```

из за неправильной кодировки дальнейшая проверка не работает

[image: скин кода]

Answer (score 1):

Заголовок PDF не является Unicode-строкой, поэтому интерпретация данных таким образом, что pBuf - указатель на широкие символы, ведёт к неверной интерпретации. Вот с использованием AnsiChar всё нормально становится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Да, кодировка у вас неправильная, но только не в том месте, в котором вы думаете.

С буфером, считанным из файла, всё в порядке, а проблема с константой `%PDF`, которая интерпретируется как юникодная строка (если вы используете [`StrlComp` из SysUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.StrLComp)).

Чтобы исправить ошибку, вам надо объявить константу как `AnsiString` и использовать указатель на неё, и вместо `StrlComp` использовать [CompareMem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.CompareMem), раз уж вы сравниваете память.

```
const
  CPdfMagic: AnsiString = "%PDF";

var
  pBuf: Pointer; // или PAnsiChar
begin
  ...
  if CompareMem(pBuf, @CPdfMagic[1], 4) then begin
    ...
```